# Wordpress How to display Post Title and its Tags in a table

Tags: wordpress, tags

Hello everyone in wordpress I was wondering how to QUERY the POST TITLE and the TAGS inside those POST. I have now queried the POST title POST date but Im missing the POST TAGS because it is located on different table and I dont know how to Select the TAGS inside each POST.
Thank you, any reply is deeply appreciated thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would soemthing like this work for you. It basically says to display everything in the left table (wp_posts) then it matches the post id's in both tables and displays tags if tags exist. Some variation of this should work for you. There might we a little screwing around to get this to work right but this is the idea anyway.

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.guid, wp_posts.date, 
othertable_othercolumn
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN othertable
ON wp_posts.ID=othertable.ID
WHERE wp_posts.post_type='post' AND wp_posts.post_status ='publish'
```

by other column i mean the column name of your tags, othertable is the name of the other table

Comment: Hello Sir thanks for the reply this is my code `SELECT ID,post_title,guid,post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status ='publish'
` This actulay displays everything I need exept the Tags inside each post because it is located in different table. I think this uses JOIN in query or something but I'am not familliar in using mysql query for separate tables. Thanks

Comment: hello Sir I think that is how it goes but to get the tags for each wordpress post is quite complicated to be clearer I'm using an wordpress plugin called export and report.. In there you will just query the tables and fields you want to generate to export to csv. I've got the other fields I want but querying the tags for each post is to complicated it is the only thing missing in my report please see here what it looks like [link](http://ldcgimutao.x10.bz/dekzgimutao/queryresult.png) thank you very much